# How to use user defined table type in DB2 with clause?

Tags: sql, database, db2

I have created a user defined table type in DB2 as follows:

```
create table fullname as (street varchar(100), addr varchar(100))
```

I want to know how to use it in a `WITH` clause to basically add the sub table columns to this udtt. The `WITH` clause is as follows:

```
WITH result (one, fullname) as
(
    select one, two, three from info
    UNION ALL
    select one, two three from other_info
)
```

I want to group columns two and three together as one column represented by the  fullname table type. Is this possible - and how is it done???

EDIT :
Suppose the two tables are defined as below

`info( one varchar(50), two varchar(50), three varchar(50) )`

`other_info( one varchar(50), two varchar(50), three varchar(50) )`

So the `WITH` clause would generate a table that is the union of both the info and other_info table and this generated table would have the schema

`result (one varchar(50), fullname )`

where `fullname` is the user defined table type that contains the two column attributes `two` and `three` from the union, as one column.

So if the table `info` contained:

`( 'Man', 'Peter', 'Griffin')`

and the table `other_info` contained:

`('Baby', 'Stewie', 'Griffin')`

then the `WITH` clause would result in the table

`('Baby', ('Stewie', 'Griffin') )
 ('Man', ('Peter', 'Griffin') )`

Comment: Could you describe with more details what the desired result should look like? You talk about concepts that you want to use, but which may not be necessary at all

Comment: And add sample table data, and the expected result!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the following SQL script, DB2 V10.5 - Linux:

```
connect to pocdb;

drop table stack.with_test_1;
drop table stack.with_test_2;
drop table stack.with_test_results;

create table stack.with_test_1 (
    one varchar(50),
    two varchar(50),
    three varchar(50)
);


create table stack.with_test_2 (
    one varchar(50),
    two varchar(50),
    three varchar(50)
);

create table stack.with_test_results (
    one varchar(50),
    fullname varchar(100)
);

insert into stack.with_test_1 values ('x','fn1','ln1');
insert into stack.with_test_1 values ('x','fn2','ln2');
insert into stack.with_test_1 values ('x','fn3','ln3');
insert into stack.with_test_2 values ('y','fn4','ln4');
insert into stack.with_test_2 values ('y','fn5','ln5');
insert into stack.with_test_2 values ('y','fn6','ln6');

insert into stack.with_test_results
with union_test as (
    select one, two, three from stack.with_test_1
    union all
    select one, two, three from stack.with_test_2
)
select
    one,
    two || ' ' || three as full_name
from
    union_test
;

select * from stack.with_test_results order by one;

connect reset;
terminate;
```

Yields these results:

```
connect to pocdb

   Database Connection Information

 Database server        = DB2/LINUXX8664 10.5.3
 SQL authorization ID   = DB2INST1
 Local database alias   = POCDB


drop table stack.with_test_1
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.

drop table stack.with_test_2
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.

drop table stack.with_test_results
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.

create table stack.with_test_1 ( one varchar(50), two varchar(50), three varchar(50) )
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.

create table stack.with_test_2 ( one varchar(50), two varchar(50), three varchar(50) )
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.

create table stack.with_test_results ( one varchar(50), fullname varchar(100) )
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.

insert into stack.with_test_1 values ('x','fn1','ln1')
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.

insert into stack.with_test_1 values ('x','fn2','ln2')
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully. 

insert into stack.with_test_1 values ('x','fn3','ln3')
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.

insert into stack.with_test_2 values ('y','fn4','ln4')
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.

insert into stack.with_test_2 values ('y','fn5','ln5')
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.

insert into stack.with_test_2 values ('y','fn6','ln6')
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.

insert into stack.with_test_results with union_test as ( select one, two, three from stack.with_test_1 union all select one, two, three from stack.with_test_2 ) select one, two || ' ' || three as full_name from union_test
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.    
select * from stack.with_test_results order by one        

ONE                                                FULLNAME                 

-------------------------------------------------- -------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
x                                                  fn1 ln1                  

x                                                  fn2 ln2                  

x                                                  fn3 ln3                  

y                                                  fn4 ln4                   
y                                                  fn5 ln5                   
y                                                  fn6 ln6                   

  6 record(s) selected.


connect reset
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.

terminate
DB20000I  The TERMINATE command completed successfully.
```